# Unable to upload to S3 with Grails S3 Demo Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, grails, amazon-s3

I am trying to run a demo project for uploading to S3 with Grails 3.

The project in question [is this](http://guides.grails.org/grails-upload-file/guide/index.html), more specifically the S3 upload is only for the 'Hotel' example at the end.

When I run the project and go to upload the image, I get an updated message but nothing actually happens - there's no inserted url in the dbconsole table.

I think the issue lies with how I am running the project, I am using the command:

```
grails -Daws.accessKeyId=XXXXX -Daws.secretKey=XXXXX run-app
```

(where I am supplementing the X's for my keys obviously).

This method of running the project appears to be slightly different to the method shown in the example. I run my project from the command line and I do not use GGTS, just Sublime.

I have tried inserting my AWS keys into the application.yml but I receive an internal server error then.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your bucket policy in s3. You need to grant permissions to the API user to allow uploads.